# Laravel - displaying errors goes wrong

Tags: php, laravel, validation, laravel-5, laravel-5.3

I have a simple page with a form for files upload.
I am validating it in controller and returning errors in the view if something goes wrong. Unfortunatelly, the alert with errors is always displaying (empty alert when no errors), even when I'm not submiting the form. Could someone please tell me how to do this in a better way?

form + error displaying:

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" method='POST' action='/add_image'>
    {{ csrf_field() }}
    <p>Wybierz zdjęcie do dodania:</p>
    <input type="file" onchange='loadFile(event)' name='fileUpload' id='fileUploadInput'> <br> <br>
    <img id="uploadPreview"> <br> <br>
    <input type='submit' name='submit' id='fileUploadSubmit'>
</form>


    @if($errors)

       <script>alert('{{$errors->first()}}');</script>

    @endif
```

validating:

```
 if($request->hasFile('fileUpload')){
            $image = $request->file('fileUpload');

            $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
               'fileUpload' => 'required|image',
            ])->validate();

        }
```

$errors var_dump output without errors:

```
object(Illuminate\Support\ViewErrorBag)#147 (1) { ["bags":protected]=> array(0) { } }
```

I just want this alert to show when any errors are there...

What else I tried was if(isset($errors)) and !empty but it isnt helping

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `$errors` object you are checking does not evaluate to `FALSE` but `TRUE` cause it is an object (a `ViewErrorBag`). That makes the `if` check pass but still blow up on the `first()` call.
What you have to do is make sure that there is any errors in the Error bag.
Try the following:

```
@if($errors->any())
  <script>alert('{{$errors->first()}}');</script>
@endif
```

Comment: This is correct, but I think `$errors->any()` would be better since that's the purpose of `any()`

Comment: @mopo922 Yeah you might be right. Rolls better on the tongue too! Ill change it ;)

Comment: Where  can I find something about any() in documentation? I cannot find it

Comment: I don't know where I learned it TBH. You're right, it's not in the documentation. If you open up the source code in `vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Support/MessageBag.php` you can see what methods are available on `$errors`

Comment: From the laravel API docs: https://laravel.com/api/5.3/Illuminate/Support/MessageBag.html#method_any